# Visual studio code no reconoce mi paquete en python

Tags: python, visual-studio

visual studio code no reconoce el paquete que he creado con python, ya he creado el archivo init y nada, adjunto imagen, agradecería mucho que me ayudaran[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que los nombres de los módulos en Python son relativos a las carpetas en las que se encuentran. El archivo **login** está en la misma carpeta que el archivo **registro**. Así que creo que deberías escribir `from registro import *`.

Comment: Por cierto, la pregunta será mejor recibida si incluís el código y el error como texto. Dejando solamente una captura del sistema de archivos.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, gracias por el consejo

Comment: Hola BAYRON, bienvenido, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!